# How to fix this code from crashing access. I assume through some error with the loop

Tags: vba, ms-access

I got it to just make a list of everything, but I need to do some grouping. my idea was to get a list of addresses, then as I loop through those addresses, filter another query with the information I want to display. If I do that, I don't get an error, but it hangs the program. I'm assuming it's a problem with the loop, but I'm not sure how. Any suggestions?

```
Public Function getActionItems(strID As String, strType As String) As String

    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim qdfAddress As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rstAddress As DAO.Recordset
    Dim s As String

    Set dbs = CurrentDb

    'Get the parameter query
    Set qdf = dbs.QueryDefs("qryActionItems")
    Set qdfAddress = dbs.QueryDefs("qryActionItemsAddresses")

    'get all records
    Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset()
    Set rstAddress = qdfAddress.OpenRecordset()

    'get all records with the submisison number
    rstAddress.filter = "submission_number=" & strID
    Set rstAddressFiltered = rstAddress.OpenRecordset

    'cycle through the addresses
    If Not rstAddressFiltered.EOF Then
        rstAddressFiltered.MoveFirst

        s = s + "<strong>" & rstAddressFiltered!Address & "</strong>" & vbLf & "<ol>"

        Do
            'filter for the address
            rst.filter = "submission_number=" & strID & "AND Address=" & """ & rstAddressFiltered!Address & """
            Set rstFiltered = rst.OpenRecordset

            'cycle through the records with the address
            If Not rstFiltered.EOF Then
                rstFiltered.MoveFirst
                Do
                    s = s + vbTab & "<li>" & rstFiltered!Address & " - " & rstFiltered!Notes & " - " & rstFiltered!Due_date & "</li>" & vbLf
                    rstFiltered.MoveNext
                Loop Until rstFiltered.EOF
            End If

        Loop Until rstAddressFiltered.EOF

        s = s + "</ol>"

    End If

End Function
```

Edit:  I think it may be that I missed the .movenext, but I haven’t had a chance to try it.

The main query has
submission_number, type, address, notes

I'm trying to get something like
123 main st

- Foo bar
- Bar foo

126 main st

- Notes

When I run the query I won't know what or how many addresses I have.  So I thought I would use query1 to grab the addresses, then use the addresses in `query1` to filter `query2`, printing those results.

If you see a better approach, I'm open!

Comment: What does stepping through the code in the debugger tell you?

Comment: I'm not certain what you are trying to do but it's entirely likely that you can replace most of this code with the correct SQL query

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid. My table has information associated with addresses.  When the query starts I don't know what or how many there will be.  There may be multiple rows with the same address so I want to group them by address.  

my idea was to get a list of addresses, then as I loop through those addresses using it to  filter another query with the information I want to display. Using nested loops to get the grouping If I do that, I don't get an error, but it hangs the program.  What sql would you suggest?

Comment: @KenWhite I don't know how to do that.  I'll have to look it up.  Thanks

Comment: There's not enough info provided to suggest a SQL query but it sounds like you are just doing a standard SQL join between two tables

Comment: See the `Debug` menu. Use F9 to set a breakpoint on the first line of your outer loop, and then run to there. Use F8 to step through the code line by line to see what it's doing. If you loop without hitting a `MoveNext`, you'll know where you missed it.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Does my edit help.

Comment: Well in theory you could return all of the data in one joined dataset and rather than do an inner query for each address, just recognise when the address value changes, and if so start another new grouping. But what you have is probably fine. Now you just have to follow existing advice and use debugging to confirm what's going on. "hanging" could be an endless loop or it could be something else. You need to understand more details about "hanging"

Comment: Why using HTML tags? Where are you using address string? I don't use QueryDefs just to open a recordset object.

Comment: @June7  I am going to be using outlook to send it, and I want the default signiture to attach.  It doesn't work that way unless I go HTML.

it's a lot simpler to use reports, sure, but unfortunately, the people I am emailing don't like the attachments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter criteria has syntax errors. Need a space in front of AND. Quote mark delimiters are wrong. Use apostrophe instead of trying to double up quote mark.

`rst.filter = "submission_number=" & strID & " AND Address='" & rstAddressFiltered!Address & "'"`

Comment: It was a combination of this, and a few other errors with how I had the loops working.  after a few tweaks I have it more or less working.